react-form-hook useFieldArray not displaying forms in my nexjs App
"use client";
import ButtonPrimary from "@/shared/ButtonPrimary";
import ButtonSecondary from "@/shared/ButtonSecondary";
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import Image from "next/image";
import Checkbox from "@/shared/Checkbox";
import FormItem from "./FormItem";
import Input from "@/shared/Input";

export interface PageAddListing7Props {
  formData: any[];
  errors: any;
  control: any;
  register: any;
  handleSubmit: any;
  prevPageHandler: any;
  nextPageHandler: any;
  setFormData: any;
  watch: any;
  setError: any;
  coverImgee: any;
  setCoverImage: any;
  image1: any;
  image2: any;
  image3: any;
  image4: any;
  setImage1: any;
  setImage2: any;
  setImage3: any;
  setImage4: any;
  data2: any;
}

const PageAddListing7: FC<PageAddListing7Props> = ({
  formData,
  errors,
  control,
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  prevPageHandler,
  nextPageHandler,
  setFormData,
  watch,
  setError,
  coverImgee,
  setCoverImage,
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4,
  setImage4,
  setImage1,
  setImage2,
  setImage3,
  data2,
}) => {
  const [multipleCategory, setMultipleCategory] = useState(false);
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "entries",
  });

  console.log("fields")
  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-14 border-b border-neutral-200 dark:border-neutral-700"></div>
      {/* FORM */}
      <form
        className="space-y-8"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit((data: any) => {
          setFormData({ ...formData, ...data });
          nextPageHandler();
        })}
      >
        {multipleCategory ? null : (
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Pictures of the hall</h2>
              <span className="block mt-2 text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                A few beautiful photos will help customers have more sympathy
                for your hall.
              </span>
            </div>

            <div>
              <span className="text-lg font-semibold">Cover image</span>
              <div className="mt-5 ">
                <div className="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-6000 border-dashed rounded-md">
                  <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                    {coverImgee ? (
                      <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(coverImgee)}
                        alt="image"
                        className="object-cover"
                        width={200}
                        height={200}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <svg
                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-neutral-400"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex text-sm text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-300">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="file-upload"
                        className="relative cursor-pointer  rounded-md font-medium text-primary-6000 hover:text-primary-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-primary-500"
                      >
                        <Controller
                          name="image_0"
                          control={control}
                          rules={{ required: "Please select a cover image." }}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <label
                              htmlFor="fileInput"
                              className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-none outline-none focus:outline-none"
                            >
                              <span className="">Upload a file</span>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="fileInput"
                                onChange={(e: any) => {
                                  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                                  if (selectedFile && selectedFile.size > 0) {
                                    data2.append("image[0]", selectedFile);
                                    console.log("settt");
                                  } else {
                                    // Handle the case when no file is selected or the file is empty
                                    setError(
                                      "image_0",
                                      "Please select a valid file."
                                    );
                                  }
                                  field.onChange(selectedFile);
                                  setCoverImage(e.target.files[0]);
                                }}
                                className="w-full absolute h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                              />
                            </label>
                          )}
                        />
                      </label>
                      <p className="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-xs text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                      PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
                {errors["image_0"] && errors["image_0"].message}
              </span>
            </div>

            <div>
              <span className="text-lg font-semibold">Picture one</span>
              <div className="mt-5 ">
                <div className="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-6000 border-dashed rounded-md">
                  <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                    {image1 ? (
                      <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(image1)}
                        alt="image"
                        className="object-cover"
                        width={200}
                        height={200}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <svg
                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-neutral-400"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex text-sm text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-300">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="file-upload"
                        className="relative cursor-pointer  rounded-md font-medium text-primary-6000 hover:text-primary-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-primary-500"
                      >
                        <Controller
                          name="image_1"
                          control={control}
                          rules={{ required: "Please select an image." }}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <label
                              htmlFor="image_1"
                              className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-none outline-none focus:outline-none"
                            >
                              <span className="">Upload a file</span>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="image_1"
                                onChange={(e: any) => {
                                  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                                  field.onChange(selectedFile);
                                  setImage1(e.target.files[0]);
                                }}
                                className="w-full absolute h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                              />
                            </label>
                          )}
                        />
                      </label>
                      <p className="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-xs text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                      PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
                {errors["image_1"] && errors["image_1"].message}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className="text-lg font-semibold">Picture two</span>
              <div className="mt-5 ">
                <div className="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-6000 border-dashed rounded-md">
                  <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                    {image2 ? (
                      <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(image2)}
                        alt="image"
                        className="object-cover"
                        width={200}
                        height={200}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <svg
                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-neutral-400"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex text-sm text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-300">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="image_2"
                        className="relative cursor-pointer  rounded-md font-medium text-primary-6000 hover:text-primary-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-primary-500"
                      >
                        <Controller
                          name="image_2"
                          control={control}
                          rules={{ required: "Please select an image." }}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <label
                              htmlFor="image_2"
                              className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-none outline-none focus:outline-none"
                            >
                              <span className="">Upload a file</span>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="image_2"
                                onChange={(e: any) => {
                                  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                                  field.onChange(selectedFile);
                                  setImage2(e.target.files[0]);
                                }}
                                className="w-full absolute h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                              />
                            </label>
                          )}
                        />
                      </label>
                      <p className="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-xs text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                      PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
                {errors["image_2"] && errors["image_2"].message}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className="text-lg font-semibold">Picture three</span>
              <div className="mt-5 ">
                <div className="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-6000 border-dashed rounded-md">
                  <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                    {image3 ? (
                      <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(image3)}
                        alt="image"
                        className="object-cover"
                        width={200}
                        height={200}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <svg
                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-neutral-400"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex text-sm text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-300">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="image_2"
                        className="relative cursor-pointer  rounded-md font-medium text-primary-6000 hover:text-primary-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-primary-500"
                      >
                        <Controller
                          name="image_3"
                          control={control}
                          rules={{ required: "Please select an image." }}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <label
                              htmlFor="image_3"
                              className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-none outline-none focus:outline-none"
                            >
                              <span className="">Upload a file</span>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="image_3"
                                onChange={(e: any) => {
                                  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                                  field.onChange(selectedFile);
                                  setImage3(e.target.files[0]);
                                }}
                                className="w-full absolute h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                              />
                            </label>
                          )}
                        />
                      </label>
                      <p className="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-xs text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                      PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
                {errors["image_3"] && errors["image_3"].message}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span className="text-lg font-semibold">Picture four</span>
              <div className="mt-5 ">
                <div className="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-6000 border-dashed rounded-md">
                  <div className="space-y-1 text-center">
                    {image4 ? (
                      <Image
                        src={URL.createObjectURL(image4)}
                        alt="image"
                        className="object-cover"
                        width={200}
                        height={200}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      <svg
                        className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-neutral-400"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <path
                          d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                          strokeWidth="2"
                          strokeLinecap="round"
                          strokeLinejoin="round"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    )}
                    <div className="flex text-sm text-neutral-6000 dark:text-neutral-300">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="image_4"
                        className="relative cursor-pointer rounded-md font-medium text-primary-6000 hover:text-primary-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-primary-500"
                      >
                        <Controller
                          name="image_4"
                          control={control}
                          rules={{ required: "Please select an image." }}
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <label
                              htmlFor="image_4"
                              className="cursor-pointer bg-transparent border-none outline-none focus:outline-none"
                            >
                              <span className="">Upload a file</span>
                              <input
                                type="file"
                                id="image_4"
                                onChange={(e: any) => {
                                  const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                                  field.onChange(selectedFile);
                                  setImage4(e.target.files[0]);
                                }}
                                className="w-full absolute h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                              />
                            </label>
                          )}
                        />
                      </label>
                      <p className="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-xs text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-400">
                      PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
                {errors["image_4"] && errors["image_4"].message}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        {/* ----------------- */}

        <div className="mt-6 flex flex">
          <Checkbox
            label="Check if you have more than one category for this hall"
            name="mutiple-halls"
            onChange={() => setMultipleCategory((prevState) => !prevState)}
            defaultChecked={false}
          />
        </div>

 /* this display on my browser*/
        <p>{multipleCategory}</p>
        {multipleCategory ? (
          <div className="space-y-8  border rounded p-4">
            {/* ITEM */}

            <FormItem label="Size (Acreage (m2))" desc="How large the hall is">
              <Input
                placeholder="..."
                type="number"
                {...register("size", {
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: "size is required", // Set your custom error message
                  },
                })}
              />
              {errors?.size && (
                <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">
                  {`${errors?.size?.message}`}
                </p>
              )}
            </FormItem>

            <FormItem
              label="Seat capacity"
              desc="The number of seats the hall has"
            >
              <Input
                placeholder="100"
                type="number"
                {...register("seat_capacity", {
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: "size is required", // Set your custom error message
                  },
                })}
              />
              {errors?.seat_capacity && (
                <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">
                  {`${errors?.seat_capacity?.message}`}
                </p>
              )}
            </FormItem>

            <FormItem label="Amount " desc="What the cost of the hall is">
              <Input
                placeholder="..."
                type="number"
                {...register("amount", {
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: "amount is required", // Set your custom error message
                  },
                })}
              />
              {errors?.size && (
                <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">
                  {`${errors?.size?.message}`}
                </p>
              )}
            </FormItem>

            <div className="flex justify-end space-x-5">
              <ButtonPrimary type="submit">{"Add Row"}</ButtonPrimary>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}


         /* this does not display on my browser*/
        {multipleCategory?
          fields.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              {/* Your form fields for each entry */}
              <FormItem
                label={`Size (Acreage (m2)) for Entry ${index + 1}`}
                desc="How large the hall is"
              >
                <Input
                  placeholder="..."
                  type="number"
                  {...control.fields[index].size}
                />
              </FormItem>

              <FormItem
                label={`Seat capacity for Entry ${index + 1}`}
                desc="The number of seats the hall has"
              >
                <Input
                  placeholder="100"
                  type="number"
                  {...control.fields[index].seat_capacity}
                />
              </FormItem>

              <FormItem
                label={`Amount for Entry ${index + 1}`}
                desc="What the cost of the hall is"
              >
                <Input
                  placeholder="..."
                  type="number"
                  {...control.fields[index].amount}
                />
              </FormItem>

              <div className="flex justify-end space-x-5">
                {index === fields.length - 1 && (
                  <ButtonPrimary type="button" onClick={() => append({})}>
                    Add Row
                  </ButtonPrimary>
                )}
                {index > 0 && (
                  <ButtonSecondary type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                    Remove Row
                  </ButtonSecondary>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )): null}

        {/* ----------------- */}

        <div className="flex justify-end space-x-5">
          <ButtonSecondary type="button" onClick={prevPageHandler}>
            Go back
          </ButtonSecondary>
          <ButtonPrimary type="submit">{"Continue"}</ButtonPrimary>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default PageAddListing7;

What I want to implement is that when I click the add row, it should clone the form to allow users to enter multiple entries, the first part where I first part of the form that does not use the useFieldArray displays on my nexjs app but to improve on it, I decided to use the useFieldArray to allow users to add a row and create more entries. the code block does not display in the browser. has anyone run into a similar issue with nextjs??
I need help, and I am not getting any error.

From the initial look it seems that your code is correct but that it might be something to do with the checkbox component:
Can you try setting multipleCategories to true initially to debug, if still not working then try adding a use effect and watch the fields property, console log to ensure its working; next step would be to remove the multipleCategory check and make sure its not that causing the error.
Another thing it could be is that you are passing an empty object to the append({}) but your map is expecting an id, this could be causing issues but it would likely throw an error rather then showing nothing.

Thank you so much for helping Devon, but after trying out all the suggestions you gave, the behavior hasn't changed.

when you tried the useEffect did it console log anything on fields changed?

Yeah..it logged an empty array.

Was that on the initial render or when you clicked the add button?
